# How do I reference the different options offered to the user, if i'm using listdlg to offer the options

Tags: string, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

```
%% LIST
physlist = {'Acceleration','Fluid Mechanics','Force','Energy','Velocity','Work'};
%% LISTDLG
[sel, ok] = listdlg('PromptString','Please select a Subtopic below:', 'ListString', physlist, 'selectionmode', 'single' );
```

If the user selects `'Acceleration'`, which is the first choice, I can simply use if `ok == 1` and run the code, though what if the user selects another option? How would I reference that choice in the same script?

I can't use `ok == 1` again can I? because I already used that for acceleration.

Is there a way I can reference each of the choices and work on their codes respectively if the user makes their selection?

Answer (score 1):

The first output argument of [`listdlg`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/listdlg.html) (variable `sel`) contains the index of the selected item.  For example, if you select `'Energy'` you get `sel==4`.

The second output argument (`ok`) is a boolean indicating whether you hit "OK" or "cancel".

I would suggest a `switch` after checking `ok`.  Something like:

```
[sel, ok] = listdlg(...);

if ok,
    switch lower(physlist{sel})
      case 'acceleration'
         % something for acceleration
      case 'fluid mechanics'
         % more code
      % ...
      otherwise
        error('Invalid selection!')
    end
end
```